# in org-mode, how to move point to next TODO heading upon DONE state change?

Tags: org-mode, hooks, todo

I work with org-mode TODO lists not in org-agenda mode, but within the actual .org files, marking TODO headings DONE as I go.

```
* DONE buy milk
* TODO fix car
* STARTED call mom
```

I want org to move point to the next TODO heading once I mark it as DONE. But not before, i.e. when I mark a TODO heading as STARTED, I want point to stay on that heading:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
  '(
(sequence "TODO" "STARTED" "|" "DONE")
```

How do I get org to move point to next TODO heading upon state change to DONE?

I tried this...

```
(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook
(lambda () (org-next-visible-heading 1)) )
```

...but it doesn't work because the hook is executed within a `save-excursion` block.

I tried this...

```
(defun bb/next-heading (&rest args)
(org-next-visible-heading 1))
(advice-add 'org-todo :after 'bb/next-heading)
```

...which works, but triggers upon ANY state change. How do I make it so `org-next-visible-heading` gets triggered ONLY when a TODO heading is marked DONE?

Comment: The answer to the first question would be either `(when (org-entry-is-done-p) (outline-next-visible-heading 1))` or the more specific `(when (string= (org-get-todo-state) "DONE") (outline-next-visible-heading 1))`.

Comment: How would I place that in a function / hook / advice?

Comment: I'd extend your `bb/next-heading` defun: `(defun bb/next-heading (&rest args) (when (org-entry-is-done-p) (outline-next-visible-heading 1)))`

Comment: Yes that works!

Comment: Put it in an answer and I'll break the other into a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `bb/next-heading` defun you could use either `(when (org-entry-is-done-p) (outline-next-visible-heading 1))` that regards all `org-done-keywords` or `(when (string= (org-get-todo-state) "DONE") (outline-next-visible-heading 1))` to be more restrictive.

```
(defun bb/next-heading (&optional arg)
  (when (org-entry-is-done-p) (outline-next-visible-heading 1)))
(advice-add 'org-todo :after 'bb/next-heading)
```

Comment: When using the `:after` keyword argument, the 'advice function' receives the same arguments as the 'advised function', therefore (currently) the `bb/next-heading` should have an argument list of the form `(&optional arg)` here.