# Assign function to one key that marks a heading DONE and jumps to the next TODO-style heading

Tags: org-mode

I would like to just use one key to mark a heading `DONE` and jump (skip all `DONE`-style headings between) to the next visible `TODO`-style heading.

I found a suggestion [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17252/in-org-mode-how-to-move-point-to-next-todo-heading-upon-done-state-change), but I get the error `apply: Wrong number of arguments: ((t) nil (if (org-entry-is-done-p) (progn (outline-next-visible-heading 1)))), 1` when I mark `TODO`s done.

The function code is

```el
(defun bb/next-heading (&optional arg)
  (when (org-entry-is-done-p) (outline-next-visible-heading 1)))
(advice-add 'org-todo :after 'bb/next-heading)
```

Comment: You need to include the source code of your function; we cannot fix it from the error message alone. However, it is likely that you are missing a parenthesis or two.

Comment: Unless you only have a single file in your agenda file list, finding TODO items is better done through the agenda. The agenda is basically a place to gather up all your TODO items and look at them through different views: possibly as scheduled items or as a list of TODO items no matter if they are scheduled or not, etc. If you have not tried it yet, I would recommend doing so - but realize that there is a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advice-Combinators.html) in the elisp manual, when using advice with the `:after` keyword argument, both functions receive the same arguments. Therefore, you should look up the argument list of `org-todo` (e.g. using `describe-function`) and use the same argument list for [your 'advice function'](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17275/26163).